# connect to a wifi network using batch or vb script

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, wifi, connect

I am trying to write a batch to automatically connect to a WiFi connection that has been set before on the system, I have tried using some other methods such as using NirCMD but unfortunately that doesn't work either.

any help would be appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: "Doesn't work" is an insufficient problem description. Please provide more details about what you have tried and how exactly that "didn't work".

Comment: Could you provide more information about the internals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command from a dos console:

> netsh wlan connect name=[wireless network]