# How to run netsh command through a batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command, netsh

I want to run the following commands through a batch file.

```
netsh
wlan
connect name=NETWORK-NAME
```

The issue is that 'netsh' and 'wlan' are unable to be done in the same line using conventional delimiters (&, &&). If I run this string as a batch file:

```
echo 1 & netsh & echo 2 & wlan & echo 3 & connect name=NETWORK-NAME
```

It outputs 1, activates netsh and stops there without executing the rest of the batch file.

Comment: `netsh` needs command line switches to function on the command line. Type `netsh /?` at the cmd prompt.

Comment: What are command line switches? Are you saying you can't run this command through a batch file?

Comment: he is saying, you don't have to enter interactive mode (with just typing `netsh`, having a `netsh>` prompt), but you can give a complete command, like: `netsh wlan show wlanreport`

Comment: possible duplicate of [connect to a wifi network using batch or vb script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039515/connect-to-a-wifi-network-using-batch-or-vb-script)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an older post, but info on the internet is forever.. so..

That actually won't work. NETSH is, itself, a **shell** like DOS is (now). You can execute that on a command line directly, but not in a batch file. Using NETSH in Batch mode is a little more complex and, in this instance, would require 2 batch files. One to launch NETSH, and another for NETSH to execute after launch.

Here is a good post on how it should be done:

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/build-your-skills-netsh-scripts-add-network-functionality-to-batch-files/

Hope this helps someone who stumbles across this.

Answer (score 2):

netsh is a program that can run either in interactive mode when you enter the program and you enter command modifiers and switch contexts one by one per line or just run the required operation in the required contect immediatelly.
So you just need to make a single string:

```
@echo off
netsh wlan connect name=profile_name ssid=SSID_name interface="Wirelss network adapter"
```

Note that ssid and interface are optional. You need to specify interface if you have several wirelss network adapters in your system - it corresponds to the adapter name. And you need to specify ssid if there are multiple SSIDs in your saved wireless network profile.

Comment: I know this is an older post, but info on the internet is forever.. so:That actually won't work. NETSH is, itself, a shell like DOS is. You can execute that on a command line directly, but not in a batch file. NETSH Batch mode is a little more complex, and in this instance would need 2 batch files. One to launch NETSH, and another for NETSH to execute..